# .xinitrc seems to be ignored if /usr/bin/xinit is called from systemd service

Tags: systemd, x11, xinit

This is on Xubuntu 18.04.

I'm trying to replace lightdm with my own application running full screen on boot up.

I can run `xinit` from root shell, and it correctly takes my /root/.xinitrc commands and runs my program full screen.

```
which xinit  #gives "/usr/bin/xinit"
```

I tried to make a /lib/systemd/system/fullscreen.service with:

```
[Unit]
Description=Fullscreen App
#Conflicts=getty@tty7.service plymouth-quit.service
#After=systemd-user-sessions.service getty@tty7.service plymouth-quit.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xinit
```

But when I run

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start fullscreen
```

It just loads an xterm terminal logged into root.

any ideas why there is any difference between the two? And how to make it run the same as `xinit` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For processes started as a system-wide service, the `$HOME` environment variable will be unset unless you specifically set it. And `xinit` will most likely use that to find `$HOME/.xinitrc` - i.e. `/root/.xinitrc` if you run the command from a root shell.

A simple way to add the environment variable would be to add this line:

```
Environment="HOME=/root"
```

to the `[Service]` section of your service file.

Comment: That makes sense! I see a lot a mixed data on the way to set ENV variables in service units... any idea on the best way?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I’ll test on next work day and then mark as accepted answer if all is well 

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you.